# Community accepted crappy suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, community-user

I came across a rather interesting [revision history](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/41068/revisions) of an question, in which was a horrible [suggested edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/4418) that was accepted by the Community bot.

To be fair, the suggested edit wasn't all bad – the tags it added were fine, but the content edits were mainly changing `Macbook` to `Mac Book` and contracting two sentences. In my opinion a rather unnecessary edit, and quite a bad one.

I'm not that informed about how Community reviews suggested edits, but it seems to be doing all right, although this one really wasn't that good. I suggest we tweak it's algorithms to reject edits splitting certain words and product names or even simply rejecting edits with only two characters edited in the main content. **Or simply not allowing community to accept suggested edits at all – there seems to be enough active high-rep users on Ask Different to handle all suggested edits by themselves.**

Answer (score 3):

That looks like something from before the redesign of /review. (Or an artifact for when a user's account is deleted). Either way, I've not seen any recent reviews by the community user.

Unless you can point to something more recent, I'm inclined to close this as status-completed at this point. It's fascinating, but likely to be a relic from the past.

Comment: Hm, you're probably right. I guess I'm a year late, huh? Thanks :)